# cURL ip address

Tags: php, curl

I need to send a curl request with the user's ip address not the server one. I tried this with no luck:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $ip );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to spoof an IP address? That is not done in PHP. I think you need to rethink what the problem is, and find another solution.

Comment: You want to spoof the IP address? That's not going to work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ok, so there's no way to safely spoof the ip address of a curl request, but I found a non-safe way, it depends on the server script receiving the request, but it worked for me to trick the API I was making the request to:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
```

This won't always work, but in this case it worked for me.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: That's not technically spoofing an IP address, it's just spoofing an HTTP header.  This is a prime example as to why you cannot rely on HTTP header validity.

Comment: yep, I know, but it may sometimes serve the purpose.

Comment: +1 but mainly so this type of problem gains visibility. It's likely the issue was with HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, which is usually used by load balancers to send the IP to the actual servers. A well behaved server, should always automatically fill the REMOTE_ADDR by the actual IP. But X_FORWARDED_FOR is a custom field, so the server can't really check it. It'd have to be checked by the load balancer.

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't work with curl for me so i found a way around it, I just had to do this and as long as the IP is assigned to your server, then:

```
echo http_socket::download('http://something.com', '55.55.44.33');

final class http_socket
{
    static public function download($url, $bind_ip = false)
    { 
        $components = parse_url($url);
        if(!isset($components['query'])) $components['query'] = false;

        if(!$bind_ip) 
        {
            $bind_ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        }

        $header = array();
        $header[] = 'GET ' . $components['path'] . ($components['query'] ?  '?' . $components['query'] : '');
        $header[] = 'Host: ' . $components['host'];
        $header[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20100106 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.5.7';
        $header[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
        $header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
        $header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate';
        $header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
        $header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
        $header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
        $header = implode("\n", $header) . "\n\n";
        $packet = $header;

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Connect to server
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        socket_bind($socket, $bind_ip);
        socket_connect($socket, $components['host'], 80);

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Send First Packet to Server
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        socket_write($socket, $packet);
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Receive First Packet to Server
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        $html = '';
        while(1) {
            socket_recv($socket, $packet, 4096, MSG_WAITALL);
            if(empty($packet)) break;
            $html .= $packet;
        }
        socket_close($socket);

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Spoofing an IP address is not something cURL can do. That's a lower-level operation requiring manipulation of raw socket connections.

Answer (score 8):

None of upper solutions has worked for me. However making a request through a proxy works very well:

```
$url = 'http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/ip.php';
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888'; //put your proxy here
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: This worked great for me except I used $proxy = 'http://'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].':22222'; and it works everytime.

Answer (score 4):

here are the lines of php code which may work.
You may use any other method to set "X-Forwarded-For" header.

```
$httpClient = new Zend_Http_Client($reqUrl);
$httpClient->setHeaders("X-Forwarded-For","127.0.0.1");  //---this sets the desired ip address
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are supposed to put your server's ip address there.

You cannot forge an IP packet with fake source address using curl.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP_X_REAL_IP header in addition with HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and REMOTE_ADDR like
"HTTP_X_REAL_IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"

Answer (score 0):

Use it into the header  add tags like REMOTE_ADDR: majbase  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: codix like "HTTP_X_REAL_IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"