# Getting IP Address of a user who sent a cURL request

Tags: php, api, curl, ip-address

I want to get The IP Address of user who sent a request to my server using cURL POST method in php ?

I'm developing a Flight API, I'll get the Requests using cURL POST method, I've to get the IP address of the client and validate weather his IP address is available or not. If available in my DB i will sent him the response by JSON.

Is it possible anyway in php ?

Comment: may be possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301319/curl-ip-address

Comment: In this case i'm trying to get the IP address of the user who sent me a request

Comment: `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`?

Comment: I'm asking this question behalf of the server. In client side i know i can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the IP address using $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] of the client who is posting to your endpoint. However if you are referring to  clients of your clients. Client1-->Client2(Who is using your API)-->You. If you want the information on Client1 you may need to relay on client2 to send you the information

Comment: Can u give me an example in cURL ?

Comment: You can't "get the Requests using cURL POST method", `cURL` is used to **send** requests, not receive them.

Comment: @Quentin: Then how to handle the user requested data from a server point of view ?

Comment: @RadhakrishnaRayidi — By using something designed to receive requests such as mod_php or a FastCGI implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the request IP address from server variable.

$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]