# How to get ip of client who sent request using curl from another server as intermediator?

Tags: php, laravel

If **UserA** hits a server **ServerA**, and **ServerA** hits a curl request On server **ServerB** and 
on server **ServerB**, What will be the IP Address? Is it of Client Machine's(UserA) IP address or **ServerA**'s IP address.

In my case I am getting ServerA's IP address, but I want to get UserA's IP address, who indirectly reaches on my ServerB through ServerA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting IP Address of a user who sent a cURL request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556208/getting-ip-address-of-a-user-who-sent-a-curl-request)

Comment: `$request->ip()` will show you the remote address that request came from, if you don't want certain servers accessing your API's, use a RBAC module like oAuth.

Comment: @Jaquarh $request->ip() gives me the ip of ServerA from where curl request was made, but I want to get the ip of User who made request through/on serverA.

Comment: Would the `X-Forwarded-For` header hold what you're after?

Comment: @Unflux X-Forwarded-For is same as $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].