# Send request with user ip when scraping data in php

Tags: php, curl

I am stuck in a problem I have a url which has a geo location restriction like it can only be viewed from europe or USA. My location is Asia. I want to extract all href's from the url.

However I am using curl but the problem is that it send server ip address and I want the request to be made with user ip address inorder to track a user which links he has visited. If you can guide me how to send request with user ip address and without using curl I'll be grateful.

Following is the source code. The url which I am accesing is:

> http://partnerads.ysm.yahoo.com/ypa/?ct=2&c=000000809&u=http%3A%2F%2Ftrouve.autocult.fr%2F_test.php%3Fq%3Dtarif%2520skoda%2520superb%2520combi&r=&w=1&tv=&tt=&lo=&ty=&ts=1458721731523&ao=&h=1&CoNo=3292b85181511c0a&dT=1&er=0&si=p-Autocult_FRA_SERP_2%3A600x796

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('iframe.html');

// find iframe from within html doc
foreach($html->find('iframe') as $iframe)
{
  $src = $iframe->getAttribute('src');     // src extracted 
  $ch = curl_init();  // Initialise a cURL handle

  // Set any other cURL options that are required
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$src);

  $results = curl_exec($ch);  // Execute a cURL request
  //echo curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);    // Closing the curl

  $bool = TRUE; $match = array(); $int = 0;
  while(preg_match('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $results, $matches))
  {
    if($bool)
    {
      // print captured group that's actually the url your searching for
      echo $matches[2].'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>';
      $bool = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also see [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301319/curl-ip-address). Sounds like you're looking for [ip spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing).

Answer (score 1):

You can use proxy.

```
$ip = '100.100.100.100:234' //example $ip
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$ip);
```

without curl:

```
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://'.$ip,
        'request_fulluri' => true,
    ),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

$sFile = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com", False, $cxContext);
```

If you lookin' for proxies, there's some adresses easy to scrape:

```
'http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/',
'http://ipaddress.com/proxy-list/',
'http://nntime.com/proxy-ip-'.$i.'.htm',
'http://www.proxylisty.com/ip-proxylist-'.$i
```

over 2000 ips

Comment: But it send server ip address when using curl , I need user ip address when request is sent to server like from which user this page has been requested