# PHP execute curl with user ip address not through server ip

Tags: php, curl

All I want is to execute a cURL request with user's IP address.

Suppose if a user's browser is *Mozilla Firefox blah blah blah.....* That's fine

but how can the user's IP address be sent with cURL request? Many websites blocked the server IP address to access through cURL.

The code sample below:

```
$ch = curl_init($ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

please help me in this code

Comment: You mean you want to forward the ip address of the client? I don't think that's possible, because then you would be spoofing a network address.

Comment: You talk about proxy. You can set a proxy server on curl

Comment: Please see answer here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301319/curl-ip-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301319/curl-ip-address)