# cURL request with user IP address in PHP

Tags: php, curl, request

I need to send a request with user IP address and not server IP address. I found similar question here ([cURL ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301319/curl-ip-address)), but it didn't help me. Any ideas what is wrong here? I did a print of **$ip** and it shows correct user IP there, so it should be okay, but it's not.

```
$curl = curl_init("MYURL");
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Spoofing IP addresses feels like something in the realm of security hacking. May I ask why you think you need it? What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: _If_ you were actually able to spoof the requesting IP, then the _response_ would be send back to the user’s IP address. Very doubtful their machine would know what to do with that response, if it doesn’t block it right away to begin with. // What you are asking here makes very little sense; you should start by explaining what _problem_ you think you would be solving this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this at all. First of all, you're trying to use another one's IP to make a request, which is basically not possible unless you're using a proxy. Secondly, if you've read the answer in the link you've provided thoroughly, what you're trying to do here is tricking the server in thinking you're another user by faking the IP in the header. This will work if the (target) server script that handles the response, **only** checks HTTP headers (which seems pretty insecure to me).

I'll try to explain it with an example. Let's say you have your user's IP which is `12.34.56.78` and your own IP is `99.88.77.66`. Then if you send a request with the header `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: 12.34.56.78` from your own server/pc (`99.88.77.66`) and the server ignores that and/or also checks `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR]` (which contains `99.88.77.66`), it will notice that it's not the user's IP who's accessing the URL, but yours.