# CURLOPT_URL with underscores, how to?

Tags: php, curl

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

My code:

```
$cu = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $cu, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $cu, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent );
curl_setopt( $cu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $cu, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file );
curl_setopt( $cu, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );
$html = curl_exec( $cu );
curl_close( $cu );
```

It works:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/Profile/123/Any/Photos/News/';
```

It doesn't work:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/Profile/123/_Any_/Photos/News/';
```

Why? What is the problem and how to solving?

Comment: `_` is unlikely to be an issue. What is the response you get? What does `print_r(curl_getinfo($cu))` give you?

Comment: The `curl_getinfo($cu)['redirect_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/?e=blocked'`, I don't understand. Why redirect and why blocked? Without _ characters in another profile URL is not blocked...

Comment: The owner of the site can tell you better about why they are blocking something. By the way, are you manually adding `_` to usernames like `Any` or is `_Any_`  is a different username altogether?

Comment: The `_Any_` profile is blocked my non-USA IP-address. The cURL, how to use proxy or USA IP-address?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301319/curl-ip-address